# How to work with input field that is created dynamically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know how to work with input field using Javascript. But when I create a input field dynamically using javascript createElement method, I am not being able to work with that. As I have not started learning PHP, I want to know how to work with dynamically created input field using javascript.

Comment: Do you have any code samples to go with this?

Comment: or at least add example

Comment: What do you mean with 'work with', getting the value in JS? Changing the value?

Comment: First you need yo create input using JS. If you did this then you should add this element into DOM (using `appendTo` for example. Then you can retrieve it by using get function like `getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

If you add an Element using `createElement` You can then work with the element by referring to the element by ID or Class.

[`document.getElementById()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Take a look [at MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for examples

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest way to track (and manipulate) the input fields is with the `getElementsByTagName();` which **returns an array of all the elements with the specified tag**.

So, as an example:

```js
// saves all current elements in an array
var inputsArr = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
console.log('Current input fields: ' + inputsArr.length);

// now let's create our new Element and set its attributes!
var newinput = document.createElement('input');
newinput.setAttribute('type', 'button');
newinput.setAttribute('value', 'Submit form');

// adds (appends) the newly created input
document.getElementById('structure').appendChild(newinput);
console.log('-- button added');

var newinputsArr = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
console.log('Current input fields: ' + newinputsArr.length);

// and we can manipulate with the newly added element
newinputsArr[2].setAttribute('style', 'background:gold;');
```

```css
input[type="button"]{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#structure {
  background: lightgray;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<form id="structure">
Login: <input type="text">
Password: <input type="password">
</form>
```

In the snippet below I showcased

1. How to fill an array with existing input elements
2. How to add a new input item and then access it
3. How to manipulate with the newly added element

Note, I intentionally created two separate arrays, as a showcase. So if you meant to manipulate eg. with only newly added elements, you can apply the the expression only to the 'extra' elements of the difference between `newinputsArr.length` and `inputsArr.length`

Comment: @SamiulIslamRohan did this answer the question for you, or some further clarification required?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add the input field to the body of the document. When you create an element with `document.createElement`, never forget to append it to the body when you are done.

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
document.body.appendChild(input);
```

```html
<span id="result"></span><br/>
<script>
var input = document.createElement("input");
input["type"] = "text";
document.body.appendChild(input);
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = "Key: "+e.key+" KeyCode: "+e.keyCode+" Value: "+this.value+e.key;
});
</script>
```